# Change User Profile Service Application database name

Tags: user-profile-service, database, database-attach

Due to some reason we are in need to rename the  User Profile Service Application.
Following the steps mentioned in below link, we started the rename activity:
[Move or rename service application databases in SharePoint Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt668003(v=office.16).aspx)

However, as per one of the steps, we should be able to give the new database name in Service Application Properties Popup. However it is showing Database Name Field as disabled. Kindly let know how we can set the new Profile, Sync and Social DB names.

Also there is confusion regarding steps mentioned in link;

- Point the service application to the moved or renamed database.
- Delete the service application.
- Recreate the service application.
- Restart the service application.

As it can be seen here, why is it so that we have to update existing service app, to set new database name and then delete and recreate it?

[image]

Comment: You cannot use the UI on BCS or UPS. You have to recreate it using your new database name(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the database-name when creating the service application through Powershell.

To do this, use `New-SPProfileServiceApplication` with the flag `-ProfileDBName`.

Documentation: 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/New-SPProfileServiceApplication?view=sharepoint-ps